# Split plain text string after dot and double space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm stuck trying to do the following, I have a big plain text string that comes dynamically, I need to add the `<p>` element to each paragraph of the string but I can't find a way to split it, basically I'm trying to divide each paragraph into an array so that then I can wrap them with the `<p>` element.

Here's one text (shortened) which is inside a div with class **'rss-diversity-description-container'**:

> Inspired by the University’s Mission values of Wisdom, Knowledge,
>   Justice, Fidelity and Association, the Lewis Community declares that
>   Lewis is a Sanctified Zone where people are committed to working to
>   end racism, bias and prejudice by valuing diversity in a safe and
>   nurturing environment.
>
> As members of the University community, we share the responsibility
>   for making equal opportunity an actual and functional condition of
>   life.  In the spirit of the Mission, the University seeks a
>   faculty, staff, and administration who reflect and respond to student
>   diversity. Through the Mission-Based Commitment to Diversity, the
>   University sets forth strategies to help turn this goal into reality.
>
> Lewis University is committed to increasing the opportunities of women
>   and minority groups at all levels and in all segments of the
>   University work force on the basis of merit and without
>   discrimination.
>
> Lewis University is an equal opportunity employer.  Decisions
>   regarding hiring, compensation, discipline, promotion, termination, or
>   other terms and conditions of employment will be made without regard
>   to race, color, religion, gender, age, national origin, disability
>   which is unrelated to the ability to perform the job or which can be
>   reasonably accommodated, or marital status. Applicants of a diverse
>   background are highly encouraged to apply.
>
> Office of Human Resources One University Parkway Romeoville, IL 60446
>   Phone: (815) 836-5270
>   Website:  http://www.lewisu.edu/welcome/offices/hr/index.htm

Basically I need to make them look like this (I shortened the text here for space purposes):

```
<p>Inspired by the University’s Mission values of Wisdom, Knowledge, Justice, Fidelity and Association, the Lewis Community declares that Lewis is a Sanctified Zone where people are committed to working to end racism, bias and prejudice by valuing diversity in a safe and nurturing environment.</p>


<p>As members of the University community, we share the responsibility for making equal opportunity an actual and functional condition of life.&nbsp; In the spirit of the Mission, the University seeks a faculty, staff, and administration who reflect and respond to student diversity. Through the Mission-Based Commitment to Diversity, the University sets forth strategies to help turn this goal into reality.</p>
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split raw text into an array of paragraphs by splitting on the newline character `\n` and then join the strings back together with p tag markup.

```js
var rawText = `Inspired by the University’s Mission values of Wisdom, Knowledge, Justice, Fidelity and Association, the Lewis Community declares that Lewis is a Sanctified Zone where people are committed to working to end racism, bias and prejudice by valuing diversity in a safe and nurturing environment.

As members of the University community, we share the responsibility for making equal opportunity an actual and functional condition of life.  In the spirit of the Mission, the University seeks a faculty, staff, and administration who reflect and respond to student diversity. Through the Mission-Based Commitment to Diversity, the University sets forth strategies to help turn this goal into reality.

Lewis University is committed to increasing the opportunities of women and minority groups at all levels and in all segments of the University work force on the basis of merit and without discrimination.

Lewis University is an equal opportunity employer.  Decisions regarding hiring, compensation, discipline, promotion, termination, or other terms and conditions of employment will be made without regard to race, color, religion, gender, age, national origin, disability which is unrelated to the ability to perform the job or which can be reasonably accommodated, or marital status. Applicants of a diverse background are highly encouraged to apply.

Office of Human Resources One University Parkway Romeoville, IL 60446 Phone: (815) 836-5270 Website:  http://www.lewisu.edu/welcome/offices/hr/index.htm

A People and a Place Committed to Diversity

Mission-Based Commitment to Diversity

In a Catholic and Lasallian University, Mission values provide the foundation for all human resource initiatives.  The achievement and continual renewal of a common vision is dependent upon employees who understand, affirm and commit themselves to common goals.  The Mission directs University human resources actions including the selection, orientation, and training of new employees as well as the growth and development of current employees.

An integral part of developing a Mission-centered workforce is to identify the values that guide the hiring process, particularly in respect to achieving a workforce that meets the needs of a diverse student population:

The value of Knowledge encourages us to become a community of learners.  A learning community engages in a wide variety of perspectives in its ongoing search for truth.  A diverse workforce enriches the community’s perspectives and enhances interactions.  The diversity of the individuals who comprise a learning community provides our students with a wide range of human experiences and relationships.

The value of Fidelity invites us to make an active commitment to diversity as an important dimension of University life.

The value of Wisdom directs us to plan creatively for education that meets the needs of a changing pluralistic society.  A diverse workforce provides the range of critical perspectives necessary to understand our students’ changing needs and the complex nature of the human community.

The value of Justice challenges us to reaffirm our commitment to overcome prejudice and change systems that oppress.  Justice also challenges the university to continue to develop programs which affirm human dignity in the workplace.

The value of Association helps us to create an authentic community within society.  This community is based upon individuals who understand, honor, and celebrate diversity as a necessary prerequisite to unity.  It is this unity that leads the community toward a common vision and the fulfillment of the University’s Mission.

Within the University’s Mission is the commitment to provide liberal and professional education programs to a diverse student population.  In the spirit of the Mission, the University seeks a faculty, staff, and administration that reflect and respond to the diversity in the general population.  It is the intent of this University Mission-Based Commitment to Diversity to set forth strategies that take into consideration diverse segments of the population. 

Lewis University:  A Sanctified Zone

Inspired by the University’s Mission values of Wisdom, Knowledge, Justice, Fidelity and Association, the Lewis Community declares that Lewis is a Sanctified Zone where people are committed to working to end racism, bias and prejudice by valuing diversity in a safe and nurturing environment. 

In 1997 Lewis University was dedicated as a Sanctified Zone during a special Founder’s Day Mass.  The Sanctified Zone has been rededicated four times since the initial dedication ceremony.  Students, faculty, and staff are consistently encouraged to respect and acknowledge the Sanctified Zone not only on campus, but also in their daily lives.  For more information about the Sanctified Zone please visit http://www.lewisu.edu/sanctifiedzone/index.htm

Office of Multicultural Student Services (OMSS)

The primary mission of the Office of Multicultural Student Services is to increase access, academic success, and retention and graduation rates for all students of color at Lewis University. It does so through advising, program development, mentoring and by promoting an appreciation of diversity throughout the campus community. This office also provides the entire campus a safe place to discuss issues around diversity in our daily lives and in developing good citizens of the world.  For more information about the Office of Multicultural Student Services (OMSS) please visit http://www.lewisu.edu/studentservices/multicultural/

University Diversity Action Team (UDAT)

The University Diversity Action Team (UDAT) organized on June 2009 with the merger of the President’s Diversity Facilitation Council and the Diversity Action Team seeks, primarily, to further develop Lewis University as a place that welcomes and affirms the equal dignity of every person.  This formally established group of students, faculty, and staff works together to promote, to support, and to develop ongoing initiatives which foster a culture of appreciation for diversity. 

The Team is composed of an Executive Team which sets the agenda for the general member’s monthly meetings.  The team is charged with providing ongoing education and awareness efforts and serves as a response group to negative acts.  UDAT is especially committed to promoting the Sanctified Zone image and message through campus print and media images related to diversity.  The team also facilitates the incorporation of diversity efforts into major campus activities including but not necessarily limited to convocation and prayer services. 

Currently, UDAT works collaboratively with the Director of Multicultural Student Services to organize events for Diversity Week.  The purpose of Diversity Week is to honor and acknowledge the gifts and legacy of Dr. Martin Luther King, Jr. His belief was that we would not survive as a people unless we recognized and acted from a global vision that embraced all of humanity, which was a focus of his work for positive social change. The institutional values of Lewis University are incorporated as they relate to Dr. King.  For more information about the purpose of the University Diversity Action Team (UDAT) please visit http://www.lewisu.edu/sanctifiedzone/purpose.htm

Lewis University is located in the Village of Romeoville, just 25 miles southwest of Chicago.  Even with its close proximity to the city, Romeoville is truly a village centered on community togetherness and social awareness.  Situated conveniently on the Des Plaines River, Romeoville is a community blossoming in both population and commerce.  In light of the recent expansion, Romeoville continues to exhibit the collaborative and cohesive spirit that has characterized the community throughout its history.  Find detailed information about the Village of Romeoville at:  http://www.romeoville.org/index.aspx`;

var formattedHTML = '<p>' + rawText.split('\n').filter(string => string.length > 0).join('</p><p>') +'</p>';

document.body.innerHTML = formattedHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @kfedorov91, it works perfectly, you're awesome! :)